# DBUnit with Oracle

Tags: oracle, exception

I am having problems with DBUnit and Oracled - I get the error message saying

```
org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException: COUNTRIES
       at org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap.add(OrderedTableNameMap.java:198)
       at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.initialize(DatabaseDataSet.java:231)
       at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:281).
```

Though I am specifying the Schema name correctly, I do not know why I get this error.

Will be grateful for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, false);
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_SKIP_ORACLE_RECYCLEBIN_TABLES, true);
```

and schema name in

```
this.dbUnitCon = new DatabaseConnection(connection, this.dbSchema);
```